# In TeamViewer, how to move toolbar to side of screen?

Tags: toolbar, teamviewer

In TeamViewer, how to move toolbar to side of screen?  It currently shows at the top of screen and covers other controls such as icons of other apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to move, but there is a small triangle button at bottom right of the toolbar to collapse it. I hope this helps

Comment: I think this is your only option

Comment: unfortunately, the small triangle button, when collapsed, is right in front of my area of interest in the other computer

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga - Use the rectangular button [|] to the left of the triangle to move the triangle's bar around (click and drag).

Answer (score -1):

You have to make it bigger, see the whole windows and then you can move it, then you have to click again so it collapse again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).